# How to change font of first word in sentence and rest of sentence in another font?

Tags: jquery, css

So im using wordpress and i display title and that title is more than one word.So i need to add in first word `font-family:'font1';` and in the rest of them to add `font-family:'font2';`. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
  <div class="main-title"><span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at index of the first space then add a specific class:

```
$('p').each(function() {
   var word = $(this).html();
   var index = word.indexOf(' ');
   if(index == -1) {
      index = word.length;
   }
   $(this).html('<span class="first-word">' + word.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + word.substring(index, word.length));
});
```

Then style  the .`first-word` class

```
.first-word{
    font-family:'font1';
}
```

For more information, see http://webdesignerhut.com/style-first-letter-word-line-and-paragraph-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: `:first-letter` is first letter, not first word